# How to search on md5 fields in elasticsearc_dsl

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, md5, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm new one Elasticsearch and elasticsearch_dsl and I've a problem, I want to make a research on md5 fields but I don't knows if I do it right.

Here is the file I've stored :

```
"data": {
        "uniqueInfo": {
                      "md5_of_my_unique_info": "a3e2c73ab0aaze73881db1a889826ada",
                       }
```

md5_of_my_unique_info is a hash of lot of value and I want to make a research to know if it exist in the database so I do this :

```
es_host = {"host": "localhost", "port": 9200}
es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[es_host])
q = Q('bool',
      must[Q('match', data__uniqueInfo__md5_of_my_unique_info=md5_value_I_want_Input)],
      )
s = Search().using(es).query(q)
response = s.execute
for hit in s:
    print(hit.meta.id)
```

I've test it on a bunch of data (15) and it seems to work but I can't test it on more data in test so can someone tell if I do it right ? if not How sould I do it ?

Thank you in advance to any one who could help me

Comment: Which type is your field? If it is "keyword" I think you will be fine, though I would use a term filter instead a match query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with JotaGe in the comment - this is fine if `md5_of_my_unique_info` is of type `keyword` (see [0] on how to set mappings in the dsl). Note that if you haven't done anything to the mappings you should have a `keyword` subfield automatically created for you by elasticsearch.

Using `term` query as a `filter` will also get you slightly better performance as elasticsearch won't have to try and calculate the score which shouldn't matter in your case, and you don't have to wrap your query in a `bool` query.

Overall your code would look like:

```
es_host = {"host": "localhost", "port": 9200}
es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[es_host])
s = Search().using(es)
s = s.filter('term', data__uniqueInfo__md5_of_my_unique_info__keyword=md5_value_I_want_Input)
response = s.execute
for hit in s:
    print(hit.meta.id)
```

Hope this helps!

0 - http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html#doctype

Answer (score 0):

my mapping is like that :
    "md5_of_my_unique_info": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
because I need to auto generate my mapping (I've json about 4000 lines)
thanks a lot for yours answer :)